# K-Mode clustering

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, initialization, cluster-analysis, data-science

I have a dataset of 6 million rows with mixed datatype. k prototype is not scalable and hence I converted all columns to categorical and ran K-mode for 4 clusters on a random sample of 4 M rows. However, k-mode has an initialization problem that will give different clusters every time you run the model. Let's say, I run it once and take the output for my analysis. Is the approach completely wrong for one time analysis? If yes, is there a way to fix initialization problem? May be by setting parameter or something. Any suggestion is deeply appreciated.

Comment: If the results vary substantially, then they likely are not very good, but rather random...

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you did this but definitely set the seed. Because once you set the mode variable it selects a random set of rows from your data and proceeds with the algorithm. So seeting the seed is important for reproducible results. I am assuming your code is something like this:

```
kmodes(data, modes=4, iter.max = 10, weighted = FALSE, fast = TRUE)
```

I hope by different cluster you don't imply the number of clusters is also changing.

Comment: hey @aditya, thank you for your response. I am using KModes(n_clusters=4, init='Cao', verbose=1,n_jobs=-2, max_iter = 100, n_init = 10, random_state =20) in python. Number of clusters does not change as I have specified 4. However, cluster centroids do change. I am assuming random_state is similar to seed in R?

Comment: @MNK yes they are the same thing. Do you need to use Cao method to do this ? If not try 'random' instead of it. I think there is some internal random initializing in the Cao method that is beyond your control.

Comment: I used 'Huang' initially but it had the same issue. Hence I changed it to 'Cao'  as it had a different initialization method I believe. I will change it to 'random' and run it once. Will keep you posted on the result. Appreciate your help!